# How to use Thymeleaf blur/onblur event to call function?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, thymeleaf

Below is my HTML and Javascript. I am using thymeleaf.All i want is to perform blur operation on this select tag i.e on blur alerting the value selected by user.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("called");
  });
});

function addSubject(){
      var x = document.getElementById("sub").value;
      alert(x);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10px;">
       <label th:text="'Subject'"></label>
          <select class="form-control" id="sub" th:onblur="'addSubject()'">
          <option value="" th:disabled="disabled" th:selected="selected" th:text="'Select Subject'"></option>
                  <option th:text="'Add New Subject'" th:value="addSub"></option>
                  <option th:each="freesub : ${detailsofexams}"
                          th:text="${#strings.capitalize(freesub)}"
                          th:value="${#strings.toUpperCase(freesub)}">
                  </option>
                </select>
              </div>
<script
  th:src="@{${@mvcResourceUrlProvider.getForLookupPath('/admin/dist/js/freecontent.js')}}"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Please try to replace | by '

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Sir , i tried the same but still not working

code : th:onblur="'addSubject()'"

Comment: Do you see an error message in the developer tool of your browser?

Comment: And where did you define the JavaScrpt method?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Sir, i just updated the code and no i am not getting any error. Also note  at the time of page loading i am able to alert "called".

Comment: Try to add 'alert('Hello'); to the onblur

Comment: Using Thymeleaf isn't doing anything for you here. Why not just use `onblur="addSubject()"`?  What is the real problem?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Sir, sorry your first comment was the correct answer. When i was changing i also updated my JS file and as you can see their is extra '});' symbols which was not allowing to JS file work properly. Sorry again

Comment: @Metroids thanks for your answer , onblur event is also working it was typo error in JS file .

Comment: That's what I thougt :-)

Answer (score 1):

Their was typo error in my JS file and as suggested by @Simon sir in first comment after doing that my code starts working. Below is correct code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("called");
  });

function addSubject(){
  alert("x");
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <label th:text="'Subject'"></label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sub" th:onblur="'addSubject()'">
              <option value="" th:disabled="disabled" th:selected="selected" th:text="'Select Subject'"></option>
              <option th:text="'Add New Subject'" th:value="addSub"></option>
              <option th:each="freesub : ${detailsofexams}"
                      th:text="${#strings.capitalize(freesub)}"
                      th:value="${#strings.toUpperCase(freesub)}">
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
```